# Multidimensional array display

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I made array like this:

```
var multiarray = {

    cat:{
        name:'hellokitty',
        legs:4
    },
    dog:{
        name:'fred',
        legs:4
    }
};
```

I just want to display, cat and dog. like this
`console.log(multiarray[0]) => cat`.
But it doesn't work.

Cat and dog are a kind of id. I'd like to display id in multidimensional object array.

Comment: That's an object with properties, it's not an array.

Comment: Here `multiarray` is an object not array. You can use `console.log(multiarray['cat'])` to get the inner `cat` object.

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```js
var multiarray = {
  cat:{
    name:'hellokitty',
    legs:4
  },
  dog:{
    name:'fred',
    legs:4
  }
};

console.log(Object.keys(multiarray)[0]);
console.log(Object.keys(multiarray)[1]);
```

As noticed in the comments, your `multiarray` is actually an object.

On the other hand, `Object.keys(multiarray)` will return an array: the list of the object keys.

Please note that Javascript does not guarantee the key (or 'property') order in an object. In other words, you should not assume that 'cat' will come first.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad you gave an explanation, I was worried that it would be left as a  *"try this"* type of answer.

Answer (score 1):

As other users noted before, `multiarray` variable is actually a prototype of `Object`, not an `Array`.

```js
var multiarray = {

    cat:{
        name:'hellokitty',
        legs:4
    },
    dog:{
        name:'fred',
        legs:4
    }
};

console.log(typeof(multiarray)); //"object"
console.log(typeof(multiarray) == Array); //false
```

All prototypes of Object's are enumerable in JavaScript. And you can iterate over keys with for ... in statement.

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an
>   object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can
>   be executed.

```js
var multiarray = {

    cat:{
        name:'hellokitty',
        legs:4
    },
    dog:{
        name:'fred',
        legs:4
    },
    ape:{
       name:'charlie',
       legs:2
    },
    elephant:{
       name:'big indian',
       legs:4
    }
};

for(var k in multiarray) { console.log(k); } //will print keys (cat, dog, ape, elephant,)
```